# Strange Behaviour in Eclipse 3.8.1

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm a newbie here. I have a simple problem in ONE java source file: the row `System.out.pritln(...)` has been treated as an erroneous expression. Here's the code snippet:

```
package vk.gui;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.itextpdf.text.BadElementException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BarcodeEAN;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCellEvent;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;


public class MatrixSheet1 {
    Properties p;
    File file;
    Document document;
    PdfWriter writer;
    Image logo = null;
    Image EANimg = null;
    float mnoz = new Double(72/25.6).floatValue();

    int IMG_WIDTH= new Double(35*mnoz).intValue(); 
    int IMG_HEIGHT=new Double(35*mnoz).intValue();
    String err=p.getProperty("cell.height");
    System.out.println("Arrgh!");   ///-------------->ERROR!
    float cell_Height = Float.parseFloat(p.getProperty("cell.height"))*mnoz;
    float cell_Width =  Float.parseFloat(p.getProperty("cell.width"))*mnoz;
```

The reported error is

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - Syntax error on token ""Arrgh!"", delete this  token
> - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

The sout and sysout shortcuts do not work neither. In other existing source files of same package everything is OK, the shortcuts work and the expression does not trigger an error.
I tried to create another source file and copy/paste the content, but I got the same error. What and where went wrong?
I need the printing just for debugging, but this is a bit annoying symptom.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try to delete the line and retype it. Sometimes, invisible characters are inserted by mistake and corrupt the file.

Comment: You are trying to execute a statement in an area of the code where only delcarations and initializers are allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you can use System.out.println() only inside methodes. If you would do something like this, it would work:

```
public class MatrixSheet1 {
    Properties p;
    File file;
    Document document;
    PdfWriter writer;
    Image logo = null;
    Image EANimg = null;
    float mnoz = new Double(72/25.6).floatValue();

    int IMG_WIDTH= new Double(35*mnoz).intValue(); 
    int IMG_HEIGHT=new Double(35*mnoz).intValue();
    String err=p.getProperty("cell.height");
    systemMessage("Argh!");
    float cell_Height = Float.parseFloat(p.getProperty("cell.height"))*mnoz;
    float cell_Width =  Float.parseFloat(p.getProperty("cell.width"))*mnoz;


    private void systemMessage(String message){
       System.out.println(message);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, you got it! At first try I got hard-coded values, so I got no need to debug it. In second stage I tried to use parameters from property file in order to use parameters, forgotting in which part of code I am actually. Many thanks.